# python speed up this regex sub

Tags: python, regex

```
p = re.compile('>.*\n')
p.sub('', text)
```

I want to delete all lines starting with a '>'. I have a really huge file (3GB) that I process in chunks of size 250MB, so the variable "text" is a string of size 250MB. (I tried different sizes, but the performance was always the same for the complete file).

Now, can I speed up this regex somehow? I tried the multi-line matching, but it was a lot slower. Or are there even better ways?

(I already tried to split the string and then filter out the line like this, but it was also slower (i also tried a lambda instead of def del_line: (that might not be working code, it's just from memory):

```
def del_line(x): return x[0] != '>'

def func():
    ....
    text = file.readlines(chunksize)
    text = filter(del_line, text)
    ...
```

EDIT:
As suggested in the comments, I also tried walking line by line:

```
text = []
for line in file:
    if line[0] != '>':
        text.append(line)
text = ''.join(text)
```

That's also slower, it needs ~12 sec. My regex need ~7 sec. (yeah, that's fast, but it must also run on slower machines)

EDIT: Of course, I also tried str.startswith('>'), it was slower...

Comment: Try `(?m)^>[^\n]*\n`, a wild guess. Not sure if it will improve anything.

Comment: @HamZa That's a lot slower.

Comment: You probably don't want to use a regex, but if you're sticking with it, I'm guessing it'll be faster if you include a "start of string" char `^`.

Comment: yes, it's `^`. edited quickly :p

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional It's by far the fastest approach so far. As shown, I tried filter(), and also walking through the file line by line (not shown)

Comment: you still walk through it line by line. what you do with each line is the important part. in this case you should: check the first char, and nothing else. I realise you tried that, just saying.

Comment: 7 seconds for 3GB? If you want it faster, buy a new computer....

Comment: What about `line.startswith()`?

Comment: @RyanP That's just my test computer, it must also run on other pcs If it would be just mine, I would be already satisfied, too ;)

Comment: Are you on Linux? Try running `time grep -v '^>' <filename>` to get a baseline time for comparison. You could also try just using grep to do this part - something like `grep -v '^>' <filename> | python myscript.py` for stdin or `python myscript.py <(grep -v '^>' <filename>)` (bash only) for a filename passed on the command line.

Comment: @RyanP : grep needs 4 sec. So, I would say that python already did a great job in matters of performance. When using grep to do the preprocessing, I still need my script to load all the remaing lines.. I'm not sure if there will be any speed-up. Thanks for your ideas. I will keep them in mind.

Comment: Also, if you are on Linux and Python is not a requirement, you may try a good ol' `sed -e '/^>/d' < input > output`, or at least use it as a reference, similarly to what @RyanP proposed (sorry I put the wrong command before).

Comment: It should be `p = re.compile('^>.*\n')` otherwise it would accept lines like "aaaa>aaaa"

Comment: There are no lines like that. It's given by the file format specifications. My regex works fine for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the chance, running `grep` as a subprocess is probably the most pragmatic choice.

If for whatever reason you can't rely on grep, you could try implementing some of the "tricks" that make grep fast. From the author himself, you can read about them here: http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html

At the ending of the article, the author summarizes the main points. The one that stands out to me the most is:

> Moreover, GNU grep AVOIDS BREAKING THE INPUT INTO LINES.  Looking for
>   newlines would slow grep down by a factor of several times, because to
>   find the newlines it would have to look at every byte!

The idea would be to load the entire file in memory and iterate with it on byte-level instead of line-level. Only when you find a match, you look for the line boundaries and delete it.

You say you have to run this on other computers. If it's within your reach and you are not doing it already, consider running it on PyPy instead of CPython (the default interpreter). This may (or may not) improve the runtime by a significant factor, depending on the nature of the program.

Also, as some comments already mentioned, benchmark with the actual grep to get a baseline of how fast you can go, reasonably speaking. Get it on Cygwin if you are on Windows, it's easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is not faster?

```
def cleanup(chunk):
    return '\n'.join(st for st in chunk.split('\n') if not(st and st[0] == '>'))
```

EDIT: yeah, that is not faster. That's twice as slow.

Maybe consider using subprocess and a tool like grep, as suggested by Ryan P. You could even take advantage of multiprocessing.

Comment: Thx! That's not faster (10 sec vs. 7 sec with my regex). multiprocessing would have been my next step anyway, I just wanted to check before, if I could still speed things up a little.

Comment: Yeah, I just timed it and it was slower than your regex.

Comment: I don't think that multiprocessing will do much here, as the problem seems to be mainly related to IO throughput.

Comment: @javidcf I tested it on SSD and HDD, same performance. There seems to be no IO bound at all.

Comment: @Eulelie Right, you said you had the text in memory, so the IO thing didn't really make much sense.